# What is classes-full-debug.jar in android

Tags: android

I want to know about classes-full-debug-jar in android. My question includes :-

1. what is the use of  classes-full-debug.jar in android? When to use it?
2. How to download it ? Is it available with sdk download ?
3. Can anybody gives me the link to go through the different package in it and what are the interfaces available in it and what are their uses?
4. Mainly i want to know about  **android.app.im.feature** package and folowing interfaces in it **IPreference, IDynamic, IInjection, IPreferenceHeader** etc.